# React native get music files

Tags: ios, react-native

```
 { [TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'RNReactNativeGetMusicFiles.getAll')]
line: 96542,
column: 37,
```

This error comes up when I try to get all music in ios.

I have executed both `pod install` and `react native link`.

Does anyone know what can be done or any other alternative for getting device music in ios in react native?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `react-native-get-music-files`

This package get all the sound files in your local and sd card for Androi and iOS, and retrive metadata from each file, also generate an blurred image from cover file.

Try

```
watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf node_modules/ && yarn cache clean && yarn install && yarn start --reset-cache
```

Comment: thats what i have already used.Im getting this error on ios its working on android.Has anyone been able to get it working on ios

Comment: Did you link library?

Comment: yes, i executed this command "react-native link react-native-get-music-files". Since that didn't change anything i did the manual linking but that straight up breaks the project